# Last record when enter its show in all return rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

Here is a code which I used to join two table and display record but when tab return and user enter it's value its change all record value and display same in all rows

```
 SELECT tab_issue.tab_tag,tab_issue.tab_imei,tab_issue.person_name,tab_issue.issue_date,tab_issue.project,tab_issue.sim_number,tab_issue.data_ava,tab_issue.asset_charger as issueCharger,tab_issue.asset_powerbank AS issuePowerbank,tab_issue.asset_powercable AS issuePowerbank,tab_issue.asset_powercable AS issuePowercable, tab_issue.asset_cover as issueCover,tab_issue.tab_condition as condition1, tab_return.return_date,tab_return.data_return,tab_return.assetR_charger AS returnCharger,tab_return.assetR_powerbank AS returnPowerbank,tab_return.assetR_powercable AS returnPowercable,tab_return.assetR_cover AS returnCover,tab_return.tab_condition AS condition2
                FROM tab_issue LEFT JOIN tab_return 
                ON tab_issue.project = tab_return.project
```

in a database table where tab_return entry[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGcUm.png) came, it's work fine one single entry.. picture attached for detail

Comment: I see a query here, but I don't see any PHP code, and I don't understand the question too

Comment: you question is not clear ..

Comment: in PHP code simply display record with echo @AlonEitan

Comment: php code:
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

            $counter = 1;

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
                  <tr>
<td><?php echo $counter;?></td>
 <td><?php if($row["returnPowercable"] != "" && $row["returnPowercable"] != null ) echo $row["returnPowercable"]; else echo "Not Return";?></td>

Comment: would you please check the query is it fine ?????
@AlonEitan